# Use Case Suggestion for Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am looking for one complete end to end use case to practice on cassandra, can someone suggest a good one to me or can share examples. I have access to a 6 node cluster.

Answer (score 1):

The only one I know, used with earlier Cassandra versions, is [twissandra](https://github.com/twissandra/twissandra), a Twitter implementation in Cassandra. I think its abandoned as project but still valid for practice.

I personally think that any exercise simulating a social network behaviour is a good gym with nosql in general.

HTH, Carlo